# Can I reduce the space between sub menu?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question about sub menu.

[image]

This is my sub menu. I would like to reduce the space between BLOG and ABOUT. You can check my site. My site is [here](http://www.samgyoyu.com).

That space is made of this code ↓

```
#masthead .top-strip nav > ul > li a{
        padding-top:26px;
                padding-bottom:27px;
    }
```

I don't want to remove this code. I have to use.

I'm try this code but It's not good. ↓

```
#masthead .top-strip nav > ul {
        padding-top:26px;
            padding-bottom:27px;
    }
```

Can I reduce the space between sub menu **only**? Please help me!

Comment: try this out with line-height: 50px; and padding: 0;

Comment: So i will give an answere to this @user3543818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spacing is caused by the padding top and bottom in your

```
#masthead .top-strip nav > ul > li a{
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:27px;
}
```

Reduce this padding and your spacing will be gone
**Update**
Try this:

```
#masthead .top-strip nav > ul > li a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display:block;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi emisfera, Thank you for your answer. Yes I know, but I can't modify that code. Because If I modify padding value, I can't click my sub menu easily. If you use F12, You can test this:)

Comment: you can if you add `display:block' after the padding

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
.color-site-white .sub-menu li a {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, user3624843 and Ashley:) Thank you for your answer. It's helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

your submenu has a padding-bottom.

give a class to those items, and give them a padding-bottom of 10, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The best and shortest solution for this is to use `line-height`.
However, this doesn't use many people.

CSS:

```
#masthead .top-strip nav > ul > li a{
    padding: 0;
    line-height: (maybe)30px;
}
```

Short explanation to `line-height`:

....................................................
.                                                  .
.                                                  .
.This ist the text with line-height  .
.                                                  .
.                                                  .
....................................................